# Subqueries using Max() and Sum()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: one for cargo details and the other for flight details:

[image: image description]

I need to find names of airlines whose fights are carrying the heaviest package.
I tried solving it using subqueries but I wasn't able to get to the result.

My query:

```
SELECT AIRLINE_NAME 
FROM FLIGHT 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT MAX(TOTAL_WEIGHT) 
              FROM (SELECT SUM(WEIGHT_IN_KG)AS TOTAL_WEIGHT 
                    FROM CARGO 
                    GROUP BY FLIGHT_NO)
              );
```

Can someone please help me understand how I can use `Max()` and `Sum()` together?

Comment: Can you please edit your post, it's hard to read :/

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your expected O/P must be Delta-DL109?

Comment: No it has to be American airline because it has 3 flights carrying different loads so the sum would be 275 kgs.@AnkitBajpai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select FLIGHT.FLIGHT_NO,FLIGHT.AIRLINE_NAME,Max(CARGO.WEIGHT_IN_KG) WEIGHT_IN_KG from CARGO 
inner join FLIGHT on FLIGHT.FLIGHT_NO = CARGO.FLIGHT_NO
group by FLIGHT_NO,AIRLINE_NAME limt 1;
```

May this can help you.

Comment: I need to write a subquery and avoid using join, hence the confusion but thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT AIRLINE_NAME 
FROM FLIGHT 
WHERE (FLIGHT_NO) = (SELECT FLIGHT_NO 
                     FROM (SELECT FLIGHT_NO, MAX(TOTAL_WEIGHT) 
                           FROM (SELECT FLIGHT_NO, SUM(WEIGHT_IN_KG) AS TOTAL_WEIGHT 
                                 FROM CARGO 
                                 GROUP BY FLIGHT_NO
                                ) X
                          ) Y
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select WEIGHT_IN_KG,t2.FLIGHT_NO,
(select AIRLINE_NAME from FLIGHT where FLIGHT.FLIGHT_NO = t2.FLIGHT_NO) AIRLINE_NAME

from 
(select MAX(WEIGHT_IN_KG) WEIGHT_IN_KG,FLIGHT_NO from 
(select SUM(WEIGHT_IN_KG) as WEIGHT_IN_KG,FLIGHT_NO from CARGO group by FLIGHT_NO) t1) t2
```

as per your suggestion, I try to code it in Subquery may this help you either.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 FLIGHT.AIRLINE_NAME from CARGO 
inner join FLIGHT on FLIGHT.FLIGHT_NO = CARGO.FLIGHT_NO GROUP BY FLIGHT.AIRLINE_NAME order by sum(CARGO.WEIGHT_IN_KG) desc
```

This will fetch the flight name carrying the heaviest package.